# Is there an inverse of python's date.timetuple().tm_yday?

Tags: python, date

So in python, this gives me the day of the year:

```
print today.timetuple().tm_yday
156
```

But is it possible for me to give it an integer and get a date object?

What I'm trying to do is get today's date and the date 30 days ago. Tried this but no go

```
print today.timetuple().tm_yday
month_ago = today
month_ago.timetuple().tm_yday = today.timetuple().tm_yday - 30
print month_ago
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the date 30 days ago, you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print datetime.today() - timedelta(30)
```

To get the nth (e.g. 25th) day of the current year, you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n = 25
print datetime(datetime.today().timetuple().tm_year, 1, 1) + timedelta(n - 1)
```

Documentation: [timedelta Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)