# Inverse of .tm_yday

Tags: python-3.x, date

I'm trying to do the inverse of calculating the yearday of a date (see code below), e.g. I would like to create a date from a integer number which is my 'yearday'.

Finding tm_day of a date:

```
from datetime import date   
d = date(2015,12,1)
yearday = d.timetuple().tm_yday
```

Finding date of an integer (e.g. 335) and a given year (e.g. 2015):

???

Comment: please add the language tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this question with help of [Is there an inverse of python's date.timetuple().tm_yday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30678174/is-there-an-inverse-of-pythons-date-timetuple-tm-yday)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_first_jan = date(2015, 1, 1)

date_new = date_first_jan + timedelta(335)
```